# Spring Basic Auth not working using BCrypt Encoding - I am getting redirected to login popup again even after entering correct credentials

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

**Below is my PasswordEncoder Class**

```java
package com.example.springsecuritybasic.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration 
public class PasswordConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**Below is my ApplicationSecurityConfig Class**

```java
package com.example.springsecuritybasic.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity

public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Autowired
    public ApplicationSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/","index","/css/*","/js/*")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails annasmithUser = User.builder()
        .username("anna")
        .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
        .roles("STUDENT")
        .build();
        
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                annasmithUser
                );
    }
}
```

**Below is my Main Class -**

```java
package com.example.springsecuritybasic;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringsecuritybasicApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringsecuritybasicApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#userDetailsService` [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#userDetailsService()):

> Allows modifying and accessing the UserDetailsService from userDetailsServiceBean() without interacting with the ApplicationContext. Developers should override this method when changing the instance of userDetailsServiceBean().

To configure a custom user, you can register a `UserDetailsService` bean rather than overriding the method

```
@Bean
protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails annasmithUser = User.builder()
            .username("anna")
            .password(this.passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
            .roles("STUDENT")
            .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
            annasmithUser
    );
}
```